# how do i import a texture/uv map for my model?

Tags: texturing, uv

I make morph targets for PoserPro, and  for a while one of the heads I was sculpting was allowing me to turn it on 'texture shaded' and let me see skin texture instead of just a white figure. But now when I do it, it just turns blue. I don't know why. Is it because the figure is now using a PSD file for textures?

So can someone tell me how I can get this working again? Is it because of the PSD file? I have it saved as a PSD in case I need to edit it again.

Forgive me if I'm not using the right terminology but I'm not great at the names of things used in 3D models

Answer (score 1):

I'd just export the texture as a normal image format from Photoshop. Therefore the original `.psd` file can still be changed.
You should be able to keep the Texture coordinate - as long as you don't drastically change your texture, new exports will still fit onto your model